# Get list of vectors from a list of those vectors' names

Tags: r

I have vectors in R:

```
a <- 1:10

b <- a + 0.1
```

I have a list

```
a_list <- list("a","b")
```

I want to get this list:

```
want_list <- list(a,b)
```

To be clear I want to see the contents of the vectors written to the console when I run `want_list`

Comment: `mget(unlist(a_list))` ?

Comment: or `lapply(a_list, get)`

Comment: my question may have an easier title to find